# Pandas Date Time

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is the data recording reported by sensor and its being updated in every 20mins
[Sensor Reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klqAB.png)

In this case, I would like to find out the outage time period. Anyone can suggest on how to find the outage time. Like in the picture shown above that the down time occurs at 40 minutes long.

Comment: Do you just want the total outage time as a sum?

Comment: yes the total outage time and its occured time